# How do I set a default xrandr mode

Tags: linux, debian-stretch, xrandr

I have a small script that I manually need to execute each day to set my refresh rate to 120Hz. This is what the script has:

```
#!/bin/bash  
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 120
echo 120Hz Has been Enabled
```

How can I set this as my default mode, each time I boot into my OS I am automatically assigned back to 60Hz. Here is my xrandr output for the display in question:

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080     60.00 + 120.00*  100.00   119.88   119.98    99.91    50.00    59.94  
   3840x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900     119.85  
   1280x960      99.99  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768     119.99    75.03    60.00  
   800x600      119.97    99.99    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480      119.99    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could accomplish this:

The first way would be to execute your script each time X starts by adding `sh path-to-my-script.sh` to your `~/.xinitrc` file

A more permanent way to do this would be to edit your `xorg.conf` file, usually located at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

First you need a modeline, to get a modeline for your resolution and refresh rate execute

```
cvt <x resolution> <y resolution> <refresh rate>
```

in your case

```
cvt 1920 1080 120
```

Then find your monitor in `xorg.conf` and add only the numbers from the modeline, it should look something like this (but with different values of course):

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "dummy_monitor"
        HorizSync 28.0-80.0
        VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
        Modeline "1920x1080" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118
EndSection
```

for more info on how to configure your xorg file you can read on [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Monitor_settings)

Comment: Sadly, none of the suggested options will work for me. I run on the BumbleBee graphic driver solution, which does not allow me to create the xorg.conf file. As soon as I create this file, and boot into my OS, I get a black screen with some errors. 

As for .xinitrc, I do not seem to have this file either. I run Deepin 15.11, which is known as the Stable version for Debian 9.

Comment: I am an idiot. I found my xinitrc file in '/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc'. However, I added a line as you suggested: 'sh /home/xxx/res.sh' but it did not work either.

Comment: @Granwille don't touch the /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc, it is normal not to have an xinitrc if you have not already created one, simply create one in your home directory. If it still does not work look for an autostart function in your desktop enviorment and add the script there

Comment: This sadly does not work either. I guess I have to Google harder...

Comment: I have a theory to why it's not working. I suppose it has something to do with the fact that I run the OS on a laptop which has a default 60Hz screen. My logic says, when I boot into the OS, that my script executes before the OS detects my HDMI plugged in monitor, and thus fails and reverts to 60Hz. But then again, this can also not be true because as soon as I boot on the OS, I close my laptop screen and log in, everything from the external monitor.  Does my script need extra work, maybe? If yes, what would I need to add to it?

Comment: @Granwille the script seems time, it's just a question of making sure thr scrern is detected when it runs, hence why I recommended an autostart in your window manager as that would probably run after the connection had been detected, perhaps you could add a sleep time at the start of the script to let it see all the screens first

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue following the steps below.

Notes:
I'm current using Debian 10 with the Gnome graphical interface and Xorg server.

I follow the instructions at Gnome documentation to add a xrandr script which changes the resolution right after user login:

#### Create a .desktop file in the /etc/xdg/autostart/ directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=xrandr
Exec=xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1280x768 --preferred
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution out there, but I haven't found it yet.

This is the Gnome documentation link:
https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/autostart-applications.html.en